# Hide function definition with enable_if

Tags: c++, c++14, sfinae, type-traits, enable-if

Can someone help me to understand why the following code does not compile:

```
#include <type_traits>

class A{};
class B{};


template< typename T >
class C
{
  template< typename = std::enable_if_t<std::is_same<T, A>::value > >
  void foo()
  {}

  template< typename = std::enable_if_t<std::is_same<T, B>::value > >
  void foo()
  {}
};
```

error message:

```
t.cpp:15:8: error: class member cannot be redeclared
  void foo()
       ^
t.cpp:11:8: note: previous declaration is here
  void foo()
       ^
1 error generated.
```

I expected that always only one definition of `foo` is active; either the first one in case of `T` is equal to `A` and the second in case of `T` is equal to `B`.

It would be great if someone can help me to fix the code.

Answer (score 2):

Directly from [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/enable_if), emphasis mine:

> A common mistake is to declare two function templates that differ only in their default template arguments. This is illegal because **default template arguments are not part of function template's signature**, and declaring two different function templates with the same signature is illegal.

In easier words, both the functions signature is:

```
template<typename>
void foo()
```

Comment: Many thanks! I fixed `template< typename = std::enable_if_t<std::is_same<T, A>::value > >` to `template< std::enable_if_t<std::is_same<T, A>::value, T* > > = nullptr` which now compiles and computes the correct result. This looks for me like a dirty hack. Is there probably a more elegant solution?

Comment: @abraham_hilbert That would solve the double declaration problem, but it won't work as SFINAE.  Have you tried actually instantiating `C`?

Comment: Yes. Actually, my code was happily a bit more complex, sth. like that: `template< typename U, std::enable_if_t<std::is_same<T, A>::value, U* > = nullptr > void foo(U) { /* ... */ }`